# MVC5 One Click Delete from Details Page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I started with the scaffolding that VS MVC 5 can create, and it was working fine, but I wanted to be able to delete records ("Interviews", in this case) from the details page.

I started by copying the markup from the delete button on the Delete page over to Details, but it would simply redirect to the Details action. How can I get a button on the Details page to run the DeleteConfirmed method?

Here is the relevant code from the controller:

```
public ActionResult Details(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    Interview interview = db.Interviews.Find(id);
    if (interview == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    return View(interview);
}

[HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
{
    Interview interview = db.Interviews.Find(id);
    db.Interviews.Remove(interview);
    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}

public ActionResult Delete(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    Interview interview = db.Interviews.Find(id);
    if (interview == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    return View(interview);
}
```

and here is the markup that I copied from the Delete page and put into the Details view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="form-actions no-color">
        <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-danger" />
    </div>
}
```

---

Here is the markup I needed to make it work:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Delete", "Interviews", new { id = Model.ID })) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="form-actions no-color">
        <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-danger" />
    </div>
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to post to the `DeleteConfirm` action. Here, you're posting to the `Details` action because you're using just `Html.BeginForm()`. You need:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Delete", new { id = Model.Id })) {
```

Comment: While this does in fact post to the Delete action (alias of DeleteConfirmed) it won't post any data, so id will be null...

Comment: Right. I wasn't paying attention to the actual contents of the form. The code works in the `Delete` view because it's just a postback to the delete URL which contains the id already. Since you're specifying the URL to post to here explicitly, the id needs to be included. Alternatively, you could also use a hidden input with the id within the form. Either way would work.

Comment: Thank you, this worked. The signature for the method also needs to include the controller name, but you got me most of the way there. I'll update my post with the final markup.

Answer (score -1):

You can get delete confirm by javascript on onclickling method like this

```
//change input type to button to prevent form submit
<input **type="button"** onClick="deleteConfirm" value="Delete" class="btn btn-danger" />
function deleteConfirm()
{
 $.ajax({
  url: "DeleteConfirmed Action Url",
  type:"post", 
  data:{id:} 
  success: function(response) {
    //check your server side result
  }
});
}
```

Comment: deleteConfirm is a server-side action method, not javascript.

Comment: you can call your serverside action by ajax calling and send result to client

Comment: But that's what the poster wants to know how to do... you're glossing over the point of the question.

Comment: Closer, but that url certainly isn't valid... if you don't know how to do MVC ajax, you should probably just delete your answer to get your rep back.